# Javascript trying to have Function appear in Alert

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I am trying to have 5 random letters or numbers appear in an alert through JavaScript.

When I run, the alert is not coming up.

Sorry I am new with JavaScript, any help would be great. Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function randomString() {
   var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   var string_length = 8;
   var randomstring = '';
   for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
 }
  document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
</script>

<script>
 function myFunction(){
   alert(randomString());
}
</script>
```

And I am using this for the button to call it.

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box">
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: The `randomString` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: You need to return something from the function. The alert can't guess what it should display.

Comment: What does being new with Java have to do with this? It's Javascript, not Java.

Comment: I didnt say I was new to Java, I am new with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
return randomstring;
```

at the end of the `randomString` function.

Answer (score 1):

Return the value of `randomstring`:

```
function randomString() {
   var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   var string_length = 8;
   var randomstring = '';
   for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
       var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
       randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
   }
   return randomstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertUser(msg) {
alert(msg);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="alertUser('Welcome to this AMAZING web page!')">
<div style="text-align:center;padding:10px;">
<h1>Amazing Web Page.</h1>
<p><a href="JavaScript:self.close();">Close</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```